# Displaying Video on Webpage from Google Glass

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I just picked up my Glass this weekend!  Very excited.  :)  I recorded a video with my Google Glass, shared it to my application, then with my web app made an oauth connection to the Mirror API and retrieved a video content type="video/mp4" and content URL (using PHP $attachment->getContentUrl()) that looks like this:

http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=f4046ce94ae5d248&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=sensitive_content%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1378342900&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=2B5CAA41215B0B582CD88D9281E8DCC6BCB8A11C.4E88965373ECF16E5A9473A2861275016ECFEB70&key=lh1

Can I use that link for embedding or should I look towards a different API for getting the proper URL so I can display my video on my website (e.g. Google Plus, Youtube API)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume that these video URLs are stable. They're only intended to be used for the scope of your API operation.

If you'd like to embed the video in a website, consider a different video hosting API like [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/).

Comment: In the past, these URLs have required auth to access, but this one appears public. Is this a change?

Comment: Yup! It's a change, but don't assume it will be this way forever. Continue to use the API methods to access video attachments.